# Grub ls shows no output

Tags: boot, grub2, grub

In the grub Shell, no Output is generated when I type "ls /", "ls", "ls ($root)" or anything like that.
Interestingly enough, I can type:

```
ls /<tab><tab>
```

and see the list of files in

```
$root
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling secure boot fixed this issue. I can now see disks and partitions as normal when doing an "ls"